# How to rewrite consecutive 'async with' statements into a loop?

Tags: python, websocket, async-await

I have the following excerpt which works fine in every regard except that it requires that I know how many WebSockets I plan to open in advance.

If instead I started with a list of hosts and had to create N WebSocket connections, how could I accomplish what this code does for 3 Websockets (via 'async with') for N in a loop?

The awaiting I already have in a loop, it's the "async with" that I cannot figure out how to "loopify".

```
async with websockets.connect('ws://192.168.0.174:81') as websocket1:
    async with websockets.connect('ws://192.168.0.194:81') as websocket2:
        async with websockets.connect('ws://192.168.0.179:81') as websocket3:

            datatosend = GetBallData()

            for socket in [websocket1, websocket2, websocket3]:
                await socket.send(datatosend)
```

Comment: I can't help, but +1 for "loopify".

Comment: Maybe this should be formulated as a self-made context manager which receives array of addresses and returns array of websockets. Like, `async with myconnector(['192.168.0.174:81','192.168.0.194:81','192.168.0.179:81']) as websockets:  for sock in websockets: .....`

Comment: But it also looks like you don't need a strict order here, so it can be rather a generator that gets array of addresses and yields websockets in random order, as they respond.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Python3.7 there is [AsyncExitStack](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.AsyncExitStack) available in `contextlib` module, this is how it can be used for your issue:

```
hosts = ['ws://192.168.0.174:81', 'ws://192.168.0.194:81', 'ws://192.168.0.179:81']
async with contextlib.AsyncExitStack() as stack:
    sockets = [
        await stack.enter_async_context(websockets.connect(host))
        for host in hosts
    ]
```